# Extending Crawlee scraper requestHandler

Tags: typescript, web-scraping, crawlee

I'm using `crawlee@3.0.4`, following the quick tutorial [here](https://crawlee.dev/docs/introduction/crawling) to spin up a scraper.

```js
import { PlaywrightCrawler } from 'crawlee';

const crawler = new PlaywrightCrawler({
    requestHandler: async ({ page, request, enqueueLinks }) => {
        console.log(`Processing: ${request.url}`)
        await page.waitForSelector('.ActorStorePagination-pages a');

        await enqueueLinks({
            selector: '.ActorStorePagination-pages > a',
            label: 'LIST',
        })
    },
});
```

I now need to extend the `enqueLinks` function which is passed to the `requestHandler`. The goal is to add some custom logics whenever I add new urls to the queue. An example usecase is keeping track of how many links of a certain type I have found, so that I can do additional logging/publishing messages to other services. Is there any way to do that?

I have tried to extend the PlaywrightCrawler class instead. My problem with that approach is since the `requestHandler` is wrapped by an object, I cannot access its properties.

```js
class CustomCrawler extends PlaywrightCrawler {
    categoryPagesQueued: string[];

    constructor() {
        super({
            requestHandler: async ({ page, request, enqueueLinks }) => {
                console.log(`Processing: ${request.url}`)
                // Wait for the actor cards to render,
                // otherwise enqueueLinks wouldn't enqueue anything.
                await page.waitForSelector('.ActorStorePagination-pages a');
        
                
                // Error: this does not access the CustomCrawler.categoryPagesQueued
                this.categoryPagesQueued.push("foo");
                customLogic(this.categoryPagesQueued);

                await enqueueLinks({
                    selector: '.ActorStorePagination-pages > a',
                    label: 'LIST',
                })
            },
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this, but not in the purest of object oriented overriding ways:

There is a good article here [enter link description here](https://blog.apify.com/how-to-scrape-the-web-with-playwright-ece1ced75f73/) that shows how to use arrow notation for the requestHandler.  It enables access to `this` context so you can incorporate your custom processing that way.

It's the only way I've found so far to execute my custom processing.

```
const crawler = new PlaywrightCrawler({
    requestHandler: async ({ request, page, enqueueLinks }) => {
        const title = await page.title()
        console.log(title);

        // Do Stuff with doStuff() defined in class ....
        this.doStuff();

        // Extract links from the current page
        // and add them to the crawling queue.
        await enqueueLinks();
    }
})
```